# Generic rules to rewrite urls

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to rewrite my urls for my website.

I've 5 pages and for all of them, I need to insert a new RewriteRule like this one:

```
RewriteRule about$ about.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule contact$ contact.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)$ article.php?i=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Is there a way I can make it more generic ?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post from which URL to which URL you want to rewrite in your questions let us know then for better understanding of the question please.

Comment: Except for the 3rd rule in your question you can have a generic rule to add `.php` extension for the given `URI`

Answer (score 1):

You probably are looking for something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,END]

RewriteRule ^/?blog/([^/]+)$ /article.php?i=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It work for the first pages but not for the blog article page.

Comment: And "does not work" means what exactly?

Comment: Could you please, as it has already been asked in the comments to the question, give an example of such a "blog article page"?